# TLE - Calculate the value sum of all 01? strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, substring

I encountered this problem during a technical assessment last week.

Given a 01 string with some characters being "?". "?" means it can be "0" or "1". Now we want to calculate the value of a string. If two consecutive character is different, the value would be 1, 0 otherwise.

For example, if the string is '00', the value of the string is 0. If the string is '01', the value of the string is 1. The value of the string '01?' will be 3, since if '?' = '0', the value of string '010' is 2, and if '?' = '1', the value of the string ''011" is 1.

The answer can be taken modulo with 10^9 since it could be quite large.

My code has runtime error:

```
def generateStrings(s):
    if '?' not in s: return [s]
    ind = s.index('?')
    s0 = s[:ind] + '0' + s[ind+1:]
    s1 = s[:ind] + '1' + s[ind+1:]
    possible0 = generateStrings(s0)
    possible1 = generateStrings(s1)
    return possible0 + possible1

allPossibleString = generateStrings(inputString)
ans = 0
for item in allPossibleString:
    for i in len(1, item):
        if item[i-1] != item[i]:
            ans += 1
print(ans)
```

I used recursion and got a time exceeded error. Is there a more time-efficient way to solve this problem? Please help!!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: The input string contained `?`, therefore `generateStrings()` called itself, which called itself, which called itself, infinitely.

Comment: Hi @ewokx! The problem should be solved within 2000ms, and mine take over 2001ms so did not pass

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon! Thank you for the reply. I have made a mistake on the code posted here. Passed 16% in the technical assessment. I have revised it, please refer to the updated code. Thank you again!

Comment: Usually when a solution exceeds the timeout in an online judge, it's killed. It would probably take a good deal longer than the timeout if they let it keep going, so don't expect shaving 1 ms will get you a pass. Also, TLE and runtime errors are different in online judges. Sounds like you have a TLE. How large an input can you be given? Do you have a link to the problem?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen. Thank you for pointing this out, it should be TLE. I just wonder if there's a more time-efficient way to solve the problem. I don't have a link since the assessment is over.

Comment: Can you provide any estimation of the input length bound? I also don't understand what "If two consecutive character is different, the value would be 1, 0 otherwise" means exactly. Can you provide an example of this case? "the value of the string ''011" is 1" also doesn't make sense. Isn't the value of "011" 3, assuming this is a binary string?

Comment: @ggorlen  Sorry, I'm not sure about the input length, In the assessment they only give a hint that a small portion of the input strings have lengths smaller than 20, my code only passed these short input strings. For the string "0 1 1", the first two consecutive characters are '0' and '1', which means the value is 1. The second two consecutive characters are '1' and '1', they are the same so the value is 0. Add together the value of '0 1 1' is 1.

Comment: So it's an XOR logic, then? OK, if your code works on small inputs then that's clear enough of a specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a linear sweep through the input list. Keep track of the number of "paths" that exist, which depends on the number of "?" you have encountered so far (every time a "?" doubles the number of paths). Whenever a bit toggle is possible, it should be counted for each path ending in the previous bit value. Note also that when a "?" is encountered, there are just as many paths that end there with a 0 as with a 1.

After looking at all possibilities, you can get to the following algorithm:

```
def generateStrings(s):
    lst = list(map(int, s.replace("?", "2")))
    points = 0
    # We start with 1 path, unless the first character is "?": then 2 paths.
    num_paths = max(1, lst[0])
    for prev, curr in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if curr == 2: # "0?" or "1?" or "??"
            points += points + num_paths  # Half of (doubling) paths get point
            num_paths *= 2  # The wildcard doubles the number of paths
        elif prev == 2: # "?0" or "?1"
            points += num_paths // 2  # Half of paths get a point
        elif curr != prev: # "01" or "10": Simple case
            points += num_paths
    return points
```

Make sure to perform your arithmetic modulo 10<sup>9</sup> if that is expected.